# How to iterate JSON data and insert results to corresponding HTML table row?

Tags: html, json, ajax

I would like to put JSON data into existing HTML table rows template, which are created dynamically.

I'm getting proper JSON data, but when I'm trying to put it into HTML table, only one row is updated.

Here is HTML table:

```html
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>E-mail address</th>
        <th>Phone number</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($users['results'] as $u) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="align-middle" id="first_name"><?= $u->first_name; ?></td>
        <td class="align-middle" id="last_name"><?= $u->last_name; ?></td>
        <td class="align-middle" id="email"><?= $u->email; ?></td>
        <td class="align-middle" id="phone"><?= $u->phone; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Table rows are dynamically generated depending from SQL query.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{"results":[
                {
                  "first_name":"Some name",
                  "last_name":"Some name",
                  "email":"email_address",
                  "phone":"666633337"
                },
                { 
                  "first_name":"Some other name",
                  "last_name":"Some other last name",
                  "email":"email_address",
                  "phone":"234234324"
                }
           ]
}
```

And here is what I've tried with AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
            url : "filter_participants",
            method : "post",
            data: { view },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.results, function(index) {      
                        $('#first_name').html(data.results[index].first_name);
                        $('#last_name').html(data.results[index].last_name);
                        $('#email').html(data.results[index].email);
                        $('#phone').html(data.results[index].phone);
                    });
                }
        });
```

When I call AJAX request, I would like to remove existing data from table rows and put new data from JSON result. Rows should be created dynamically based on JSON data and AJAX request should be able to update corresponding number of created rows.

For instance:

If there are 2 rows in JSON data, AJAX should remove all existing rows and put JSON data into 2 new rows.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed to solve my problem. Here is the answer:

1 . First of all, I need to edit HTML table, remove id's from td tag and add a custom class for tr tag:

```html
<?php foreach($users['results'] as $u) { ?>
<tr class="ajax-data">
    <td class="align-middle"><?= $u->first_name; ?></td>
    <td class="align-middle"><?= $u->last_name; ?></td>
    <td class="align-middle"><?= $u->email; ?></td>
    <td class="align-middle"><?= $u->phone; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

2 . Create a proper AJAX action, which will remove all table rows and create a new ones with data coming from server in JSON format:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "filter_participants",
    method : "post",
    data: { view },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var tr = '';
        $('tr.ajax-data').remove();
        $.each(data.results, function(index) {
            tr += '<tr class="ajax-data">';
            tr += '<td class="align-middle">' + data.results[index].first_name + '</td>';
            tr += '<td class="align-middle">' + data.results[index].last_name + '</td>';
            tr += '<td class="align-middle">' + data.results[index].email + '</td>';
            tr += '<td class="align-middle">' + data.results[index].phone + '</td>';
            tr += '</tr>'
        });
        $('tbody').append(tr);
    }
});
```

That's all. Feel free, if You have some suggestions.